# my program skips .addListenerForSingleValueEvent when trying get data from firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use firebase realtime database and my code skips .addListenerForSingleValueEvent.

I tried to catch exception and debugging but it always skips it. there is a connection to the db because I can insert values just not retrieve.

here's the function:

```
public void getAllUsers(final DatabaseCallback<ArrayList<User>> callback) {
        try {
            ArrayList<User> userArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            DatabaseReference usersRef = database.child(TABLE_USERS);
            usersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot usersSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        User user = usersSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        userArrayList.add(user);
                    }
                    callback.onSuccess(userArrayList);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    callback.onFailure(error.toException());
                }
            });
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            callback.onFailure(new Exception(e));
        }
    }
```

```
public interface DatabaseCallback<T> {
        void onSuccess(T result);
        void onFailure(Exception e);
}
```

Comment: `addValueEventListener` is asynchronous and never throws an exception. try/catch will not work here.  Errors will surface in the `onCancelled` callback. Query results will surface in the `onDataChange` callback. Those callbacks are not immediate.

Comment: it skips onCancelled is being skipped too

Comment: Have you tried to get the code out of the try-catch? Does it work that way?

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudFirestore/).